# How to configure VIM ALE to use cookstyle linter

Tags: vim, chef-infra, vim-plugin, neovim, vim-ale

I am trying to configure VIM plugin [ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) to use chef [cookstyle](https://docs.chef.io/workstation/cookstyle/) linter for chef cookbooks projects. But ALE is not throwing any errors. On the documentation I found out [ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) has options for chef-based cookstyle https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/blob/master/doc/ale.txt, but it's not working.

I have defined the following configuration in my vimrc file
[image: ALE configuration for cookstyle]

Comment: What is the output for `:ALEInfo`? Also in question use text instead of an image.

Comment: If I paste :ALEInfo output  in text it will exceed the total character limit enforced by stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `ale_linters` for Chef [distributed with ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/tree/master/ale_linters/chef), so it would be a matter of setting your `filetype=chef` for these Ruby files matching a certain directory path.  This can be done with something like (of course, adjust accordingly to your local directory structure):

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead */recipes/*.rb set ft=chef syntax=ruby
```

Then when running `:ALEInfo` you will see output like:

```
 Current Filetype: chef                                                                                                                
Available Linters: ['cookstyle', 'foodcritic']
  Enabled Linters: ['cookstyle', 'foodcritic']
  Ignored Linters: []
 Suggested Fixers:
  'remove_trailing_lines' - Remove all blank lines at the end of a file.
  'trim_whitespace' - Remove all trailing whitespace characters at the end of every line.
 Linter Variables:
let g:ale_chef_cookstyle_executable = 'cookstyle'
let g:ale_chef_cookstyle_options = ''
let g:ale_chef_foodcritic_executable = 'foodcritic'
let g:ale_chef_foodcritic_options = ''
 Global Variables:
...
```